# How to force display of x-axis labels in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with some small size charts in Highcharts, and it seems that due to the size Highcharts is showing labels for only alternating ticks on the x-axis. What I'd like to do to show the label for every tick on the x-axis, even if it means using a smaller font. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

I'm loading csv data from a pre HTML block.
Here's the code:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

<div id="chart_left_1" style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 350px; height: 200px;"></div>
<pre id="gdpgr" style="display:none">year,gdp_yoy,us_gdp_yoy,
2009,1.9000,-2.1000,
2010,7.6000,3.8000,
2011,6.0000,3.7000,
2012,0.9000,4.1000,
2013,-0.1000,3.2000,
2014,5.8000,4.1000,
</pre>

$(function () {
$('#chart_left_1').highcharts({
chart: {
        borderColor: '#000080',
    borderRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    title: {text: 'GDP Growth', margin: 0},
    exporting: {enabled: false},
    legend: {enabled: false},
    subtitle: {text: null},
    xAxis: {
        },
    yAxis: {
         tickInterval: 2,
      title: {text: null},
         labels: {
         formatter: function() {
          return this.value + '%';
          }
         },
    },
    tooltip: {
       enabled: true,
   valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('gdpgr').innerHTML,
        startRow: 1,
        endRow: 11,
        endColumn: 2,
        firstRowAsNames: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: ' GDP growth',
        color: '#000080'
},{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'US GDP Growth',
        color: '#CCCCCC'
    }]
  });
});
```

And Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/otfq0dch/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, if you dont need to use other type of xAxis than category, you can use step label's property.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  allowDecimals: false,
  labels: {
    step: 1
  }
},
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/otfq0dch/3/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the xAxis is defined twice, i consolidate and added a new option called tickInterval which is set to 1

https://jsfiddle.net/otfq0dch/2/

```
xAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    tickInterval: 1
},
```

link to the docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

Answer (score 0):

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    allowDecimals: true,
    labels: {
    step: 1
    }
  },
```

Comment: Please add context

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.